# AWS Lambda Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-kinesis, aws-lambda

Hello I have made an AWS Lambda function for Kinesis stream for batch size of 100 & I am trying to execute it in multi-threaded environment but the problem is that in multi-threaded environment,it works very slow compare to single-threaded ..  Like I can share you the numbers :    For 512 MB with 60 seconds timeout,Lambda function executes 955 records in 684 ms & 1031 records in 435 ms & For multithreaded it executes 430 records in 878808 ms & 433 records in 893862 ms for same memory (i.e. 512 MB & 60 second timeout)

Following is my Lambda function code which is executing in multi-threaded behaviour:

```
public String myHandler(final KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, final Context context) {
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            //@Override
            public void run() {
                int singleRecord=0;
                long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                //LambdaLogger lambdaLogger=context.getLogger();
                for(KinesisEventRecord rec : kinesisEvent.getRecords())
                {
                    singleRecord=0;
                    System.out.println("Kinesis Record inside is:"+new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
                    //count++;
                    singleRecord++;
                    //  System.out.println(new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
                }
                count=count+singleRecord;
                long endtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                long totaltime = endtime-starttime;
                time=time+totaltime;
                System.out.println("Time required to execute single Lambda function for "+singleRecord+" records is"+" :: "+totaltime+" milliseconds");
                System.out.println("Total time required to execute Lambda function for "+count+" records is"+" :: "+time+" milliseconds");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        return null;
    } //end of handler method
```

Does Lambda function executes slow in multithreaded environment? I want to know what might be the reason behind the slow processing of this multithreaded Lambda function? If I want this function to work faster than single-threaded function then what changes should I do in this code?

Comment: Clearer now, thanks. But still - where's the benefit of starting a new thread per execution element?

Comment: @Jan http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-gs.html != java 8 lambda function, similar in concept though since you define a function to run in the cloud.

Comment: @Akshay: can you share singlethread code as well to compare? Where is `count` defined?

Comment: I don't know why it's so much slower with a thread but it's not going to become any faster by moving the code from the thread that receives the request to a new thread and then waiting on that background thread to finish. If you want to make it faster with multithreading you have to do something in parallel. You still have only 1 active thread in your code - plus the overhead of creating a new thread. AWS will schedule your lambda as much in parallel as it sees fit. There is no need to write non-blocking handler methods.

Comment: Yeah I have shared the single-threaded code below.....

Comment: By the way I want to make clear that is multithreading an AWS Lambda function possible ??

Answer (score 2):

Two further options:

1. Have your initial Lambda use the SDK to asynchronously launch further lambdas that actually do work (fan out)
2. Use Lambda scheduling with scheduling offsets and long timeouts, so that you have multiple lambdas running concurrently.